# Problem with feeding PointCloud2 messages from SwissRanger 4000 to Octomap Server

Tags: ros, pcl, octomap, octomap-mapping, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get the PointCloud2 messages published by swissranger_camera node and feed it to octomap_server which subscribes to "cloud_in" (PointCloud2).  I am available to visualize the point cloud in RViz.  However, when I run the octomap_server node, it is constantly giving me the PCL error:

```
[pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane::optimizeModelCoefficients] Not enough inliers found to support a model (0)! Returning the same coefficients.
```

Here is the launch file for octomap_server I am using:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="octomap_server" type="octomap_server_node" name="octomap_server">
    <param name="resolution" value="0.05" />
    
    <!-- fixed map frame (set to 'map' if SLAM or localization running!) -->
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="map" />
    
    <!-- maximum range to integrate (speedup!) -->
    <param name="max_sensor_range" value="5.0" />
    
    <!-- data source to integrate (PointCloud2) -->
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/swissranger/pointcloud2_raw" />

</node>
```

The octomap_server also gives two warnings:

1. No plane found in cloud.
2. No ground plane found in scan.

The PCL error and the warnings seems to happen when octomap_server is doing ground plane filtering. Does it imply that the PointCloud2 output by the swissranger_camera is not good/clean enough and I have to do some processing with it before I feed it to octomap_server?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30909/problem-with-feeding-pointcloud2-messages-from-swissranger-4000-to-octomap-server/) by [hank0113](https://answers.ros.org/users/2092/hank0113/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-03-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you actually need the built-in ground plane filter? For mere map building there's usually no need and you can set the parameter `~filter_ground` to false. By default (in the latest version of octomap_server), it should be false.

Otherwise you usually need to adjust the PCL plane detection parameters to your sensor, it is currently tuned to the PR2's stereo camera by default. Best have a look at the code, not all parameters are explained on the wiki site in detail.

---

*Edit:*
There was also a problem with pointcloud transformations in the released version 0.3.7 for electric, that was fixed in octomap_mapping trunk but not yet released (see [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/30909/problem-with-feeding-pointcloud2-messages-from). A maintenance release 0.3.8 for electric will be pushed out soon, otherwise you could use octomap_mapping from SVN.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1